# Add-in Warning: License Information Missing or Expired

Tags: excel, office-js, office-store

I am getting following error in Office Excel Add-in I developed using office.js, only on some machines.

Our add-in is a free. I have also found a few people [complaining about this behavior for their free add-ins](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/2aae16b7-bb17-4765-8b00-f594fa5b5384/license-error-with-published-app?forum=officestore). It seems that this behavior is noticeable on few customer machines.

[image]

My manifest file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OfficeApp 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0" 
    xmlns:ov="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides" xsi:type="TaskPaneApp">
    <Id>masked</Id>
    <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
    <ProviderName>Invensys Systems Inc.</ProviderName>
    <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
    <DisplayName DefaultValue="Configuration Assistant for Wonderware Online" />
    <Description DefaultValue="Execute administrative tasks against your Wonderware Online InSight subscription."/>
    <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://online.wonderware.com/TagAdministrator/Images/icon-administrator-x32.png"/>
    <SupportUrl DefaultValue="https://www.wonderware.com/contact/contact-support ">
        <Override Locale="en-US" Value="https://www.wonderware.com/contact/contact-support " />
    </SupportUrl>
    <AppDomains>
        <AppDomain>https://wonderware.auth0.com</AppDomain>
    </AppDomains>
    <Hosts>
        <Host Name="Workbook" />
    </Hosts>
    <Requirements>
        <Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.2">
            <Set Name="ExcelApi" />
        </Sets>
    </Requirements>
    <DefaultSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://online.wonderware.com/TagAdministrator/" />
    </DefaultSettings>
    <Permissions>ReadWriteDocument</Permissions>
</OfficeApp>
```

My addins from Office Store

- [Data Assistant for Wonderware Online InSigh](https://store.office.com/en-us/app.aspx?assetid=WA104380532&sourcecorrid=b28aa201-879f-4f51-8371-8fb961b78265&searchapppos=0&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&appredirect=false)
- [Configuration Assistant for Wonderware Online](https://store.office.com/en-us/app.aspx?assetid=WA104380531&sourcecorrid=b28aa201-879f-4f51-8371-8fb961b78265&searchapppos=1&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&appredirect=false)

Comment: Could you add your manifest file (with ID and URI's masked if you wish) to your question?

Comment: i have added the manifest file.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-MSFT, Has there been a resolution to this? We are also facing this problem. We use Add-in commands in our manifest but, it's also distributed free as a trial with in-app purchases (outside of Office Store)

Comment: We are having issues on some latest client too.

Comment: I have one user seeing this as well.

Comment: our client has the same issue